# How to show image through javascript file

Tags: javascript

I would like to know, how i can show a image through my javascript code.

Example:

javascript.php:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/show_image.php"></script>';
```

show_image.php:

```
echo '<img src="http://domain.com/image/show_image.png" />';
```

This will not show anything. Anyone know why? :)

Comment: You can simply show the image including your php file with include('show_image.php');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be:

```
echo 'document.write("<img src=\"http://domain.com/image/show_image.png\">")';
```

above assumes proper content-type for response

```
header('Content-type: text/javascript', true);
```

Comment: I need to do it in a <script>, any ideas?

Comment: This would probably generate invalid XHTML because the <img> would be added after the closing </html>, no?

Comment: It all depends on where the script tag is placed, if I understand correctly, document.write drops the added content where the script tag is.

Comment: You don't need to give that second argument to `header()`, as it defaults to `TRUE`.

Comment: @Dre, yes, scripts are executing in-place, unless defer attribute is set.

Answer (score 1):

Because `script` elements are not designed to show images.

Use `include 'show_image.php'`.

Comment: I need to do it in a <script>, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the `<img>` to appear where the `<script>` is, first change the `<script>` to something like this:

```
<script id="imagePlace" type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://domain.com/show_image.php"></script>
```

Then change show_image.php to this:

```
var scr = document.getElementById('imagePlace');
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute("src","http://domain.com/image/show_image.png");
scr.parentNode.insertBefore( img, scr );
```

Comment: Hello Andrew.
I tried this solution, but without luck:
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var scr = document.getElementById(\'imagePlace\');
var img = document.createElement(\'img\');
img.setAttribute("src","http://domain.com/image.png");
scr.parentNode.insertBefore( img, scr );
  
  </script>';